# cookie string get and set properties for jquery control

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone help with two functions that I need. I want one function to get a property value from a cookies string taht matches a controls id and the other to set a property value for a controls id. My string looks like this

```
var cookieValue='id=1&state=normal&theme=purple:id=2&state=maximized&theme=pink';
```

The string has to be split with a colon cookieValue.split (':') for each control properties; and when setting a propertyValue the cookieString must be updated and joined together does someone know how to do this.

the functions would look like this

```
function setPropertyValue(cookieString, id,  propertyName, propertyValue) {
    if(id) setProperty_Value
    return cookieString;
}

function getPropertyValue(cookieString, id, proprtyName) {
     return propertyValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function setPropertyValue(cookieString, id,  propertyName, propertyValue) {
  cookieObjects = cookieString.split(':');
  for (var i = 0; i < cookieObjects.length; i++)
  {
    cookieObject = cookieObjects[i];
    if (cookieObject.indexOf("id=" + id) >= 0)
    {
      cookieProperties = cookieObject.split("&");
      for (var j = 0; j < cookieProperties.length; j++)
      {
        cookieProperty = cookieProperties[j];
        if (cookieProperty.indexOf(propertyName) >= 0)
        {
          return cookieString.replace(cookieProperty, cookieProperty.split("=")[0] + "=" + propertyValue);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return propertyValue;
}

function getPropertyValue(cookieString, id, propertyName) {
  cookieObjects = cookieString.split(':');
  for (var i = 0; i < cookieObjects.length; i++)
  {
    cookieObject = cookieObjects[i];
    if (cookieObject.indexOf("id=" + id) >= 0)
    {
      cookieProperties = cookieObject.split("&");
      for (var j = 0; j < cookieProperties.length; j++)
      {
        cookieProperty = cookieProperties[j];
        if (cookieProperty.indexOf(propertyName) >= 0)
        {
          return cookieProperty.split("=")[1];
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return propertyValue;
}

var cookieValue='id=1&state=normal&theme=purple:id=2&state=maximized&theme=pink';

alert(getPropertyValue(cookieValue, "1", "state"));
cookieValue = setPropertyValue(cookieValue, "1", "state", "not");
alert(cookieValue);
```